# Property screen.orientation is undefined on Chrome

Tags: javascript

since 10/19/2015 the property `screen.orientation` is undefined on Chrome 46.0.2490.71 (64-bit).

According to the [docs](https://w3c.github.io/screen-orientation/), this property has this sub-properties : `angle`, `onchange` and `type`.

The property I was using is the `angle`, with means 0 - landscape or 90 - portrait. Can anyone tells me why this property is missing?

This only happens on Windows 10 or Windows Server 2012.

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'angle' of undefined at
>   $jscomp.scope.Plugin.computeLayout_ (chrome-extension://joabdphlghkbahegchlcmhbaaijcgghj/_modules/mfaihdlpglflfgpfjcifdjdjcckigekc/gen_index.min.js:125:302) at
>   $jscomp.scope.Plugin.doLayout_ (chrome-extension://joabdphlghkbahegchlcmhbaaijcgghj/_modules/mfaihdlpglflfgpfjcifdjdjcckigekc/gen_index.min.js:122:383) at
>   $jscomp.scope.Plugin.initializeWindow_ (chrome-extension://joabdphlghkbahegchlcmhbaaijcgghj/_modules/mfaihdlpglflfgpfjcifdjdjcckigekc/gen_index.min.js:98:175) at
>   null.
>   (chrome-extension://joabdphlghkbahegchlcmhbaaijcgghj/_modules/mfaihdlpglflfgpfjcifdjdjcckigekc/gen_index.min.js:95:238)

Comment: With [tag:ionic] this return `undefined` and as well with `screen.angle`.

I only have this options: availHeight, availLeft, availTop, availWidth, colorDepth, height, pixelDepth, width

Even on Mozilla Developer Network does not exist a page for this property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/screen/orientation